# How to calculate the total resistance of this complex circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

how do I calculate the resistance of the following complex circuit?
[image]

Comment: I would define three current loops, and then write and solve three voltage loop equations.

Answer (score 0):

This type of electric circuit is called star-delta configuration. You have two star configuration, so you can take three resistance linked by a vertex and trasform them into a delta configuration and continue until you can sum them with parallel or series addition of resistance.
See this image I took from https://www.electrical4u.com/delta-star-transformation-star-delta-transformation/.

[image]